# Javascript function not operating correctly as not editing the paragraph id specified

Tags: javascript, html, css

I cannot get this javascript function to operate correctly and I don't know how to describe the problem. To summarise, clicking the button should display the text of the two javascript objects.

There are 2 global objects that the functions should be able to access, but the function does not activate or the function does not perform correctly.

Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong?

```js
var property1 = new property("Commercial", "£150k");
var property2 = new property("Residential", "£300k");
// global variables

function PropertyFunction(type, value) {
  this.type = type;
  this.value = value;

  document.getElementById("js-objects").innerHTML = "Property 1 is a " + property1.type + " property with a value of " + property1.value + "<br>Property 2 is a " + property2.type + "property with a value of " + property2.value + "<br><br>The two properties are the buildings (also called properties) and the methods are displaying the property type and property value.";
}
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

/* CSS Document */

body {
  height: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  margin: 0;
}

#javascript-essentials {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #eff2f7;
}

#javascript-programming-techniques {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #F0F9FC;
}

.divider {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background: #CCC;
  display: block;
  margin: 10px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 25px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 10px;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 20px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 10px;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 16px;
  display: block;
}

#js-objects {}
```

```html
<!-- Checklist: Creating Javascript Objects -->
<!-- Checklist: Add Properties to Objects -->
<!-- Checklist: Add Methods to Objects -->
<!-- Checklist: Create Object Instances -->
<article class="divider">
  <h3>Javascript Objects</h3>
  <p>Clicking the button should display text of two javascript objects.</p>
  <p id="js-objects"></p>
  <p>NOT WORKING!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!</p>
  <button onclick="PropertyFunction()">Click Me</button>
</article>
```

Comment: Where is `property` function defined?

Comment: `PropertyFunction` expects two arguments, but you're not supplying any arguments when you call it.

Comment: Check your console log for errors.

Comment: Why are you assigning to `this.XXX` in `PropertyFunction()`? It's not an object method, so `this` is the global `window` object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the definition of the `property` function, and it looks like you put its constructor code into `PropertyFunction`.

```js
function property(type, value) {
  this.type = type;
  this.value = value;
}

var property1 = new property("Commercial", "£150k");
var property2 = new property("Residential", "£300k");
// global variables

function PropertyFunction() {
  document.getElementById("js-objects").innerHTML = "Property 1 is a " + property1.type + " property with a value of " + property1.value + "<br>Property 2 is a " + property2.type + "property with a value of " + property2.value + "<br><br>The two properties are the buildings (also called properties) and the methods are displaying the property type and property value.";
}
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

/* CSS Document */

body {
  height: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  margin: 0;
}

#javascript-essentials {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #eff2f7;
}

#javascript-programming-techniques {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #F0F9FC;
}

.divider {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background: #CCC;
  display: block;
  margin: 10px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 25px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 10px;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 20px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 10px;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 16px;
  display: block;
}

#js-objects {}
```

```html
<!-- Checklist: Creating Javascript Objects -->
<!-- Checklist: Add Properties to Objects -->
<!-- Checklist: Add Methods to Objects -->
<!-- Checklist: Create Object Instances -->
<article class="divider">
  <h3>Javascript Objects</h3>
  <p>Clicking the button should display text of two javascript objects.</p>
  <p id="js-objects"></p>
  <p>NOT WORKING!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!</p>
  <button onclick="PropertyFunction()">Click Me</button>
</article>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're calling your function via the button `<button onclick="PropertyFunction()">` but you are not passing any parameters.

This fails because your function needs two arguments: `type, value`

Also. I see this error on your console:

> **Uncaught Reference** Error: property is not defined

This means that `property` in `new property()` is not defined.

To fix this write your JS in this manner:

```
function Property(type, value) {
    this.type = type; 
    this.value = value;
    return this;
}

function PropertyFunction() {
    var property1 = new Property("Commercial", "£150k");
    var property2 = new Property("Residential", "£300k");
    document.getElementById("js-objects").innerHTML = "Property 1 is a " + property1.type + " property with a value of " + property1.value + "<br>Property 2 is a " + property2.type + "property with a value of " + property2.value + "<br><br>The two properties are the buildings (also called properties) and the methods are displaying the property type and property value.";
}
```

Comment: Javascript doesn't get an error when there's an argument number mismatch.